# Rails 3 Devise will look for the sign up page even though is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this new Rails app. I installed Devise. I don't want people registering for new accounts so I deleted the `appname/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` file

but when I try to access the delete page, I should get a "no routes" error or something similar, but instead, Rails looks for the Sign Up page here `/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.5.2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

I don't want the sign up page to be accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `:registerable` symbol from the list of devise stuff in your `User` model. This will disable the sign up feature.